# How to access nested attributes in views?

Tags: nested-forms

I am building my first rails app and struggling to get my nested attributes for categories appear in my users/show view.

views/users/show

```
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<h1>Your Cars:</h1>

<ul>
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <% current_user.cars.each do |car| %>
    <h2> <%= "#{car.make} #{car.model}"%></h2>
    <h2> <%= car.year%></h2>
    <h2> <%= car.color %></h2>
      <% if car.awards.any? %>
      <h2>Awards:</h2>
      <% end %>
        <% car.awards.each do |award| %>
          <li><%= award.title %></li>
          <li><%= award.year %></li>
          <li><%= award.description %></li>
          <% award.categories.each do |category| %>
          <li><%= category.name %></li>
          <%end%>
          <li><button class="btn btn-default"><%= link_to 'Delete Award', award,  :data => {:confirm => "You Sure?", :method => :delete}  %></button></li><br>
          <%end%>
      <button class="btn btn-default"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_car_path(car) %></button>
      <button class="btn btn-default"><%= link_to 'Delete', car,  :data => {:confirm => "You Sure?", :method => :delete}  %></button>
      <button class="btn btn-default"><%= link_to 'Add Award', new_car_award_path(car) %></button>

  <%end%>
<%end%>
</ul>

<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <button class="btn btn-default"><%=link_to "Add a car", new_user_car_path(current_user)%></button>
<%end%>
```

category.rb

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :award
end
```

award.rb

```
class Award < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :car
  has_one :user, through: :cars
  has_many :categories
  validates :year, length: {is: 4}
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: lambda {|attributes| attributes['kind'].blank?}
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]
  has_many :cars
  has_many :awards, through: :cars

   def self.from_omniauth(auth)
     where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
       user.email = auth.info.email
       user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
     end
   end

end
```

views/awards/form

```
<%= form_for [@car, @award] do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %><br>

  <%= f.label :year %>
  <%= f.text_field :year %><br>

  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %><br>

  Categories:
  <ul>
    <%= f.fields_for :categories do |categories_form| %>
      <li>
        <%= categories_form.label :name %>
        <%= categories_form.text_field :name %>
        <%= categories_form.check_box :_destroy%>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>

  <%= f.submit %>

<%end%>
```

users_controller#show

```
  def show
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:user_id])
  end
```

schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180221183858) do

  create_table "awards", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.integer "car_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.text "description"
  end

  create_table "cars", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "make"
    t.string "model"
    t.integer "year"
    t.string "color"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "award_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "provider"
    t.string "uid"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["provider"], name: "index_users_on_provider"
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    t.index ["uid"], name: "index_users_on_uid"
  end

end
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of getting the categories from the nested form to show up on my views/user/show page? I am currently only getting shown the awards, with no categories from the nested form. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add your `users_controller#show` method?

Comment: added to the bottom, thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Do you have an `award_id` in your categories table in your database (look in your schema.rb)

Comment: And by the way. You don't have to use `find_by` - it's by default id Rails is looking for, so you can write: `User.find(params[:user_id])`

Comment: Maybe just add your schema.rb file

Comment: Added the schema!

Comment: thanks for the heads up about the rails default

Comment: I've tried to create your setup on my own computer and the categories are shown as they should. It doesn't look like i can help.

Comment: Are you sure they are created after all? The categories... Have you checked with a debugging tool or in your rails console?

Comment: You seem to have a reject lamda in your accepts_nested_attributes_for that checks for an attribute in the categories that does not exist in your schema. That seems like a good place to start.

Comment: I have and I don't think they are being created.. any idea why that may be the case? Thanks so much for trying this out, does it seem to be working on your end the way that I have it set up?

Comment: @tashows That was the issue, all is working now, can't believe I missed that! Thanks so much for your help guys!

Comment: Posting that as an answer as well so you can mark this as resolved

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a reject lamda in your accepts_nested_attributes_for that checks for an attribute in the categories that does not exist in your schema.